# DOM element vertical align JS algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written the following script that takes an element's children and vertically aligns them using CSS.
The script works well in all major browsers I've tested, except IE.

Since I am changing the position values of the elements I set the width and height of the container object and the top and left of the children to they will appear in the same place once the script is done. IE doesn't handle offsetTop/offsetLeft very well.

Keeping the size of the container:

```
element.style.width = element.offsetWidth + 'px';
element.style.height = element.offsetHeight + 'px';
```

Keeping the position of a child:

```
child.style.top = child.offsetTop + 'px';
child.style.left = child.offsetLeft + 'px';
```

Alignment of a child:

```
child.style.top = parent.offsetHeight / 2 - child.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
```

Any ideas?

Improvements to the algorithm will also be happily accepted.

http://jsfiddle.net/barmatz/ZLnTx/

Comment: Why aren't you using CSS to do it?

Comment: Its because IE hates the web and it makes me cry.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not make sense. I see no reason why simple vertical alignment of elements should be a problem that needs JS to solve.

Comment: It has nothing to do with IE, you can align vertically in IE.

Comment: `top: 50%` and `margin-top: -halfOfContainersWidth` works in IE, AFAIK (with `position: absolute`)

Comment: The point is not to do it using CSS in the traditional way.